# Where should I save my external python script to be executed in FME?

Tags: python, fme-form

I need a path, because there are so many folders and subfolders :)
FME is installed C:\apps\FME\python

Tnx,

Comment: you should add some more detail to this question - where have you installed FME etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it really matters, but it might make sense to save it in the same folder as the workspace is stored, and reference it as {FME_MF_DIR}myscriptname.py

Then if you ever move them to a different location, it all should work w/o needing to be updated.